# DD-WRT DNSMasq logging help

Tags: logs, dns, dnsmasq, dd-wrt

I recently installed DD-WRT on my Netgear R7000 router and want to log DNS queries. So far without much luck.

I'm running DD-WRT v24-sp2 kongac, build 23900M.
syslogd is running and currently writing to `/var/log/messages`. I also have the firewall logging to the same directory which is working.

I have DHCP and DNSMasq enabled with `log-queries` as an additional option, but nothing extra is being written to syslog.

The options set in `/tmp/dnsmasq.conf` are currently set to:

```
interface=br0
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.dnsmasq
all-servers
domain=<my domain>
dhcp-leasefile=/tmp/dnsmasq.leases
dhcp-lease-max=57
dhcp-option=lan,3,192.168.1.254
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-range=lan,192.168.1.100,192.168.1.149,255.255.255.0,1440m
dhcp-host=<host 1>
...
...
stop-dns-rebind
log-queries
```

Using `tcpdump` I can see DNS queries being made, but nothing is being logged.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching and digging, I found that dnsmasq logging was disabled on the firmware image I was using. (source: https://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=649213)

I upgraded the firmware to 24760M and logging worked.